# What constraints should I be aware of when generating mio's Tokens?

Tags: rust, identifier, mio

[The `mio` library](https://github.com/carllerche/mio) for asynchronous I/O relies on the developer to provide instances of [the `Token` type](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/master/mio/struct.Token.html) in order to correlate events that have happened back to the source, e.g. a particular [`TcpStream`](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/master/mio/tcp/struct.TcpStream.html) or [`Handler::Timeout`](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/master/mio/trait.Handler.html).

As you can see from [the implementation](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/master/src/mio/token.rs.html#2), `Token` is just a wrapper type around a `usize`. It's tempting to simply increment a counter each time a `Token` is needed, but it will eventually overflow.

What rules should I keep in mind as I go to generate `Tokens` to pass to the [`EventLoop`](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/master/mio/struct.EventLoop.html)? Some specific questions:

- If I have two threads who each have their own `EventLoop`, can they both use `Token=0` to listen for events on two different streams? (i.e. are `Tokens` bound to a particular `EventLoop` instance?)
- Can I use `Token=0` to simultaneously represent both a `TcpStream` and a pending `Timeout`, or are they both stored in the same collection of Tokens?
- Is there any harm in jumping from `0` to `1,000,000`? (e.g. Are they being stored in a data structure that's optimized for sequential numbers?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version: `mio` doesn't actually do anything with the tokens except pass them back to you when you receive the corresponding event, so you can use whatever tokens you want as far as `mio` is concerned. To answer your questions individually:

> If I have two threads who each have their own EventLoop, can they both use Token=0 to listen for events on two different streams? (i.e. are Tokens bound to a particular EventLoop instance?)

Sure, that's fine.

> Can I use Token=0 to simultaneously represent both a TcpStream and a pending Timeout, or are they both stored in the same collection of Tokens?

`mio` doesn't have a collection of tokens. If you don't need unique tokens to identify things in your application code, you're free to use the same token in different places. (I'm a bit confused by this question though, since as far as I can tell, timeouts don't use mio `Token`s at all)

> Is there any harm in jumping from 0 to 1,000,000? (e.g. Are they being stored in a data structure that's optimized for sequential numbers?)

No. As I said above, mio doesn't care about the value of your tokens.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. The [timeout_ms](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/master/mio/struct.EventLoop.html#method.timeout_ms) method of EventLoop takes a parameter called 'token', but I didn't notice that it's not of type 'Token'. I'm surprised that the Tokens aren't being stored somewhere; does mio not pre-allocate Slabs for keeping track of the connections it maintains? How is it maintaining an association between the Token I provide and the OS notification that a Stream is readable?

Comment: No, I don't think mio really tracks the connections at all. The tokens are passed to epoll/kqueue when registering a file descriptor and epoll/kqueue pass them back up with the events. I don't really know much about the internal data structures of epoll or kqueue, but I don't think they use the tokens to identify anything (looking at the man pages, mio tokens are just opaque 'user data' as far as the underlying APIs are concerned).